# Should I mention that I am visiting my fiancé on a tourist visa?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, tourist-visas

I am a 27 year old girl from India and my fiancé and I have been in a long distance relationship for 7 years. During this time, I have visited the US 6 times, each time for a month or two. However, in 2021 during my last visit, I ended up staying for 6 months due to the second wave of Covid-19. I eventually left on the date stamped on my passport. We are getting married in India in December and I will apply for an H4/fiance visa afterwards.

I want to visit my fiancé next month for a month (on a tourist visa), but I am worried about what I should or should not mention at immigration. I was questioned once at SFO about why I visit so frequently and that scared me. Is it okay to not mention that I am visiting my fiancé if I plan to visit next month, considering I stayed for 6 months 1.5 years ago?

Comment: Where are you planning to get married?

Comment: It’s never a good idea to lie to Immigration officers, especially if that might mean what you say is inconsistent. What did you tell the officer at SFO when you were questioned?

Comment: We’re getting married in December. And I had said most of my friends live there, which is infact true and all our annual trips get planned there. They only seemed to be concerned about the money, once convinced they seemed okay. This was in 2019.

Comment: Please sign in to the account you posted the question with, so you can edit and comment.

Comment: We are getting married in india! So, now what would be the ideal answer regarding my purpose of visit at SFO border control? I’ll have my return flight booked.